# Javascript AJAX not working on ASP.NET C# and returns a 404

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a front end code which sends a POST request to the server and returns nothing as the server needs the information.However in Chrome's log i see a 404
Thanks,

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

The following code sends the server a request:

```js
   

 var data = "hi"
     var theIds = JSON.stringify(data);
                var UrlFixer = '/Process/Complete';
                // Make the ajax call
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: UrlFixer,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { ids: theIds },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert('Yay! It worked!');
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Oh no :(');
                    }
                });
```

Backend(C#):

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Quiz3
{
    public class Process
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public static void Complete(string[] ids)
        {
            String[] a = ids;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the path using browser? What happens?

Comment: `public class Process` - shouldn't you, uh, inherit from `Controller`?

Comment: Your data looks odd as well.  You've stringified a string value and then added it as a value to a property of an object.  Just add it as a regular object property and let the ajax call handle it.

Comment: Try with absolute url rather than relative as http://<hostname>/process/complete

Comment: Adding to @John, you also have to setup routing to map your requests

Comment: Hello!  Praveen it gives me a 404

Comment: Yes Archer i am trying to send an array instead of a string.

Comment: @Drag13 can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Have a look at my edited C# code and still returns a 404

Comment: Mmm, probably it will be better if you create application from Visual Studio Templates, like WebApi. Cause there are few points to be done.  You can check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: If i do restart does this mean i have redesign my whole webpage again?

Comment: you can copy your done work to the new proj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help from the code below to send data.

You do not have to submit a string item in the form { ids: theIds } You must change the form to JSON.stringify(data) .

```
var data = "Your Name";
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/Complete',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.success);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

And your class should not be simple. You must have a controller class

Backend:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public void Complete(string Name)
    {
        //Code ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe send your Ids as a list of id and don't stringify your list

```
public static void Complete(List<T> Ids)
```

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)

Comment: Hello! i am willing to transfer a Array that is why i am using stringify

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work with MVC Empty template by the following method:

Firstly a controller is made(inside the controller folder) and its named 'SubmitController'.Now at first i thought that naming it controller at the end is not important but it turns out it is and the URL would be '/Submit' and not '/SubmitController'.
Inside the C# file a function is made and i called it 'Process' with an POST attribute(HttpPost).The URL now would be '/Submit/Process'.In my case i needed to pass an array from the client to server and that is the extra piece of code used in C# to process it and display on the Output page of Visual studio.

### SubmitController.cs

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    
    namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
    {
        public class SubmitController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
        {
            [HttpPost]
            public PartialViewResult Process(string myArray)
            {
              String[] Items = myArray.Split(new char[] { ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
              //print
               Items.ToList().ForEach(i => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
    
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

### SendEvent.js

```
// Make the ajax call
            var myArray = data; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Submit/Process',
                data: { 'myArray': myArray.join(',') }, 
            });
```